# realmOC can't update data

Tags: swift, realm

addobject is success. but i want to update data. After `realm.beginWriteTransaction()` executes, breakpoint can't continue execute `backup.quanId = 5`, it's like just jump over.

```
class YQQuanBackup: RLMObject {
    dynamic var groupId:Int = 0
    dynamic var quanId:Int = 0
    dynamic var content:String = ""
}

GCDBlock.async(.Default) {
    let results:RLMResults = YQQuanBackup.objectsWhere("groupId == %d", self.groupInfo!.groupId)
    let quanBackup = results.firstObject() as? YQQuanBackup
    guard let backup = quanBackup else { return }
    let realm = RLMRealm.defaultRealm()
    realm.beginWriteTransaction()
    backup.quanId = 5
    backup.content = YQRichTextUtil.richTextToPublishText(self.textView.attributedText, uploadedImageUrls: self.uploadedImageUrls)
    do {
        try realm.commitWriteTransaction()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: You're using an old version of Realm? You should consider upgrade your version. The latest one is RealmSwift 0.98.6.

Comment: Hmm, that's really curious. That code looks fine to me. The only thing I can think of is that since it's on the background thread, it might be waiting for a Realm write to finish up somewhere else in your app. Have you tried running it on the main thread?

Comment: after set primary key to model,then it's work.